When is $G(R)\rightarrow G^{\textrm{ad}}(R)$ surjective?
Consider a reductive group $G$ over a field $k$. The adjoint group $G^{\textrm{ad}}$ is defined by the exact sequence $$1\rightarrow Z(G)\rightarrow G\rightarrow G^{\textrm{ad}}\rightarrow 1$$The sequence $$1\rightarrow Z(G)(R)\rightarrow G(R)\rightarrow G^{\textrm{ad}}(R)\rightarrow 1$$ fails to be exact for a general $k$-algebra $R$, but is exact for $R=K$, the algebraic closure of $k$. Is there a criterion to determine for which $R$ the above sequence is exact? I'm mainly interested in the case that $k$ is a non-Archimedean local field, $G$ is a split $k$-group (namely $G=\textrm{SO}_{2n}$, $G^{\textrm{ad}}=\textrm{PSO}_{2n}$), and $R=k$.

$\require{AMScd}
$In this answer, $k$ is a nonarchimedean local field.

Lemma 1.
Consider a short exact sequence of linear algebraic $k$-groups
$$ 1\to C\overset i\longrightarrow G\overset j\longrightarrow G'\to1$$
where $G$ and $G'$ are reductive, and $C\subset G$ is central and smooth.
Then we have an exact sequence of groups
\begin{equation}\label{exact}
C(k)\overset i\longrightarrow G(k)\overset j\longrightarrow G'(k)\overset\delta\longrightarrow
                                           H^1(k,C)\overset {i_*}\longrightarrow H^1(k,G)\overset {j_*}\longrightarrow H^1(k,G')
\end{equation}
in which the group structures on $H^1(k,G)$ and $H^1(k,G')$ are defined as in Section 6 of [BK].

Proof. The exact sequence of groups and sets is constructed in [S], Section I.5.
It remains to show that $i_*$ and $j_*$ are homomorphisms.
Let $T\subseteq G$ and $T'\subseteq G'$ be compatible maximal tori.
Let $G^{\rm sc}$ denote the universal cover of the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ of $G$.
Consider the homomorphism
$$ \rho\colon G^{\rm sc}\twoheadrightarrow [G,G]\hookrightarrow G.$$
Write $T^{\rm sc}=\rho^{-1}(T)\subset G^{\rm sc}$.
We identify $(G')^{\rm sc} =G^{\rm sc}$ and $(T')^{\rm sc} =T^{\rm sc}$.
Consider the commutative diagrams with exact rows
$$
\begin{CD}
G'(k) @>\delta >>H^1(k,C) @>{i_*}>> H^1(k,G) @>{j_*}>> H^1(k,G')\\
@.   @|        @V\sim V{\rm ab}V   @V\sim V{\rm ab}V\\
     @.            H^1(k,C) @>{i_*}>>{\Bbb H}^1(k,T^{\rm sc}\to T) @>{j_*}>>{\Bbb  H}^1(k,T^{\rm sc}\to T')
\end{CD}
$$
in which the vertical arrows are bijections defining the  abelian group structure on $H^1(k,G)$ and $H^1(k,G')$;
see [B] and Section 6 of [BK].
Since  the horizontal arrows in the bottom row are group homomorphisms,
the horizontal arrows in the top row are homomorphisms as well,  as required.
Now ${\rm char}(k)\neq 2$,  $G={\rm SO}_{2n}$, $C=Z_G$, $G'=G^{\rm ad}:= G/Z_G$.

Lemma 2.
$\#H^1(k,C)\ge 4$.

Proof. Since $C\cong\mu_2$, we have $H^1(k,C)={\rm Hom}({\rm Gal}(k^s/k),\mu_2)$.
We know from  Section II.5 of [N], that $k^\times/(k^\times)^2$ has cardinality at least 4.
The lemma follows.

Lemma 3. $\#H^1(k,G)=2$.

Proof. The Galois cohomology set $H^1(k,G)=2$ classifies
the isomorphism classes of quadratic forms of dimension $2n$ with given determinant.
There is exactly two isomorphism classes: with Hasse invariant $1$ and $-1$, see Chapter VI of [O'M], and the lemma follows.
Alternatively,
consider the algebraic fundamental group $M=\pi_1^{\rm alg}(G)=X_*(T)/\rho_*X_*(T^{\rm sc})$.
Then $M\cong{\Bbb Z}/2{\Bbb Z}$, and by [B] or [BK] we have
$$H^1(k,G)\cong (M_{\Gamma_k})_{\rm Tors},$$
the torsion subgroup of the group of coinvariants of the Galois group $\Gamma_k={\rm Gal}(k^s/k)$ in $M$.
Clearly, we have
$$  (M_{\Gamma_k})_{\rm Tors}= M_{\rm Tors}=M={\Bbb Z}/2{\Bbb Z},$$
and the lemma follows.

Calculation.
Let $G={\rm SO}_{2n}$ for $2n\ge 4$ over a non-archimedean local field $k$ of characteristic not 2.
Then  by Lemmas 2 and 3, the homomorphism $i_*$ in the exact  sequence (1) is not injective.
It follows that the homomorphism $j\colon G(k)\to G^{\rm ad}(k)$ is not surjective.

References
[B]  Mikhail Borovoi,
Abelian Galois cohomology of reductive groups,
Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. 132 (1998), no. 626.
[BK] Mikhail Borovoi and Tasho Kaletha,
Galois cohomology of reductive groups over global fields,
arXiv:2303.04120.
[N] Jürgen Neukirch,
Algebraic number theory,
Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1999.
[O'M]
O. Timothy O'Meara,
Introduction to quadratic forms,
Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2000.
[S]
Jean-Pierre Serre,  Galois Cohomology,
Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1997.

This is exactly what I've been looking for, thank you!

This calculation over a local field can be done with the results of [B]. With the results of [BK], one can do similar calculations over global fields, and also take into account base change.
